# Click outside an element doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
function showAll(el){
  var id = el.parentNode.id;
  var all= document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName('items')[0];

  if(all.style.display === 'block'){
    all.style.display = 'none';
  } else{
    all.style.display = 'block';
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = e.target.className;
      if(e.target != all){
        all.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="selected" onClick="showAll(this);">
    </div>
    <div class="items" style="display: none">
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically what i want to achieve is: click on `selected` to display `items` which is now hidden after that if i click again on `selected` or if i click outside of `items`(a random spot on that page or even on `selected`) i want to be able to hide `items`.

The problem is that without the `EventListener` when i click on `selected` it works to display `items` and then if i click again on `selected` it works to hide `items` but if i click on a random spot it doesn't work to close `items`.

But when i add `EventListener` and i click on `selected` it works to click a random spot to close `items` but it doesn't work to click `selected` again to close `items`.

Can anybody help me with a full JavaScript explanation, please?

Comment: What is `carts`? Shouldn't it be `all`?

Comment: @JonathanLam, yep :D

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use highly reusable code. I use `change()` and `id_()` on my web platform all of the time and it's very direct and simple. In the below example the second parameter will make the class empty (you can also use `id_('items').removeAttribute('class')` for a cleaner DOM (Document Object Model)).

**HTML**

```
<input onclick="change(id_('items','');" type="button" value="Display Items" />
<div clas="hidden" id="items"><p>Items here.</p></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function change(id,c)
{
 if (id_(id)) {id_(id).className = c; if (id_(id).className=='') {id_(id).removeAttribute('class');}}
 else if (id) {id.className = c; if (id.className=='') {id.removeAttribute('class');}}
 else {alert('Error: the class id \''+id+'\' was not found or has not yet been imported to the DOM.\n\nNew class intended: '+c);}
}

function id_(id)
{
 if (id == '' && window['console']) {console.log('Developer: empty id called from: '+id_.caller.toString().split('function ')[1].split('(')[0]);}
 return (document.getElementById(id)) ? document.getElementById(id) : false;
}
```

This code exists from years of refining the same platform instead of industry standard drama of pointlessly changing things. You are two clicks from finding more highly reusable functions on my platform's JavaScript documentation from the link in my profile.

Comment: It's more crossbrowser safe if you check (typeof window.console == typeof undefined) than checking if a non existing document might somehow magically parse to false in some browsers.

Comment: @ChrisS. That part of the code was put in place for people who are using very old browsers and I haven't had any compatibility issues with it all these years however if you *do* find a browser/version it's not compatible with please share.

Comment: I was pretty sure that old browsers or scenarios with "use strict" will throw errors but they don't, or at least I was not able to reproduce it (Just tested myself). (However it would absolutely make sense if they did, in my opinion) +1 for pointing me on my misstake there.

Comment: @ChrisS. It's cool, I test for both errors and warnings. Thankfully JavaScript warnings always seem to be valid while CSS warnings tend to be pointless. I try to ensure my work degrades gracefully and provides a browser upgrade page when the user is using something from the dark ages.